# Adding multiple Link headers in a node server

Tags: node.js

How can I do it?

```
res.header('Link' , '<' + link + '>; rel="' + rel + '"; title="' + title + '"' );
```

seems to overwrite, not append.

Answer (score 0):

It is intended to set the header value to new one. To keep the old one you would have to do something like this :

```
res.setHeader('Link' ,res.getHeader('Link')+'<'+link+'>;rel="'+rel+'";title="'+title+'"');
```